# -Wshadow=global considers enum class entry shadowing a global. Why?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

When compiling with -Wshadow=global on GCC 7.3 and 8.2, the compiler warns that the following code snippet shadows.

```
constexpr int A = 0;

class Bar {
public:
    enum Bars {
        A = 0
    };
};

enum class Foo {
    A = 0     // warns this entry shadows global declaration of A
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}

<source>:11:9: warning: declaration of 'A' shadows a global declaration [-Wshadow]
     A = 0
         ^
<source>:1:15: note: shadowed declaration is here
 constexpr int A = 0;
               ^
```

Because enum classes require the enum class name when referenced, my understanding is that all three declarations of `A` are separate: `::A`, `::Bar::A`, and `::Foo::A`.

Clang 7 doesn't emit a warning with -Wshadow.

Is this a valid shadow warning, and if so, why?

Comment: I share your understanding. Interested in seeing how this turns out.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  Seems like all versions of GCC warn about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been a bug that has been already filed about this issue titled ["`-Wshadow` generates an incorrect warning with enum classes"](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55776) . However, it is not confirmed that this is a bug.

[Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) argues that this is not a bug and gives the following example.

> ```
> typedef unsigned char foo;
> enum class myenum
> {
>   foo,
>   bar = (foo)-1
> };
>
> Is the value -1L or 255?
> ```
>
> If I rename `myenum::foo` to `myenum::Foo` the code silently changes meaning.
>
> It also changes meaning if I reorder the declarations of `myenum::foo` and `myenum::bar`, which is exactly the sort of fragile code that deserves a warning.

This is true for the example posted in the question as well. If the global `int A` is declared **after** the `enum class Foo`, there is no longer a warning.

Another user agrees on that thread:

> In an ideal world we would only warn when ambiguity exists (in the user mind), that is, at "bar = (foo) -1". However, that is probably much more difficult and expensive than the current warning.

Comment: Interesting. Why wouldn't the compiler warn about regular enums in this case? It doesn't have consistent behaviour.

Comment: Probably because a enum belonging to a class would be disambiguated by the class name. Modifying the example in the answer. Some like this: https://godbolt.org/z/3WgiE2

Comment: Let me clarify. In the question's example I'm not allowed to declare `enum class Foo { A = 0 };`. But I am allows to declare `class Bar { enum Bars { A = 0 }; };`. This seems in consistent. It's failing the enum class because `A` might refer to the global `A`. This is also true for the enum declared in the class. Therefore this should fail both cases. Instead it is inconsistent and only fails one.

Comment: Yes. I agree. It's inconsistent. Maybe it is too expensive for the compiler to detect this in all cases. Just my speculation.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can consider a silly scenario,

```
enum class Foo {
    A = 0,    // warns this entry shadows global declaration of A
    B = A
};
```

So the reference to `A` in the definition of `B` can be from global `A` and local `A`.

Comment: Why wouldn't warn about the enum in the class then?  They both shadow `::A`

Comment: that is a good question, I guess it is not a required diagnostic from compiler? I need to check the standard.

Comment: None of these are diagnostics required by the standard.  This is more static analysis being done by the compiler to help find bugs.